# how to print slice content on new line on console?

Tags: go

is there any way to store each element of slice on new line ?
something like this :

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

instead of

> 1
> 2
> 3

i just dont want to print these elements on new line but want to store elements each on separate line

here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
 

slice := []int{1, 2, 3}
fmt.Println(slice)

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What code are you using to print ? We can't fix a code you don't show.

Comment: just updated query . please suggest

Comment: what do you mean by storing in different lines ?

Comment: i mean , can we put/index new line character after each element in slice so that if i just print the slice content , then it should show content in vertical manner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type VSlice []int

func (s VSlice) String() string {
    var str string
    for _, i := range s {
        str += fmt.Sprintf("%d\n", i)
    }
    return str
}

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Print(VSlice(slice))
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: thanks. can we restore the slice with new content (with new line ?)

Comment: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `strings.Join`

```
stringSlices := strings.Join(slice[:], "\n\n")
fmt.Print(stringSlices)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in which of the two methods is faster - printing a slice using a for loop, or joining a slice and then printing the result, so I tested it. Turns out printing is *usually* slightly faster, although sometimes there's a marginal difference in favour of using strings.Join.

Here's the code:

```
func printSlice(s[] string) {
    for _, el := range s {
        fmt.Println(el)
    }
}

func joinSlice(s[] string) {
    joinedSlice := strings.Join(s[:], "\n")
    fmt.Println(joinedSlice)
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    printSlice(dirs)
    printTime := time.Since(start)

    start = time.Now()
    joinSlice(dirs)
    joinTime := time.Since(start)

    fmt.Printf("printSlice: %v \njoinSlice: %v \nprintSlice faster?: %v\n", printTime, joinTime, printTime < joinTime)
}
```

"dirs" is a slice containing a list of files - in this case over 140 files. Here's the execution time over 10 tests (I'm not aware of a more elegant way to test this in GoLang, but if anyone knows, feel free.)

```
1
printSlice: 1.584753ms 
joinSlice: 39.132467ms 
printSlice faster?: true

2
printSlice: 1.195512ms 
joinSlice: 30.53137ms 
printSlice faster?: true

3
printSlice: 1.355297ms 
joinSlice: 80.888305ms 
printSlice faster?: true

4
printSlice: 1.347343ms 
joinSlice: 32.668568ms 
printSlice faster?: true

5
printSlice: 1.317251ms 
joinSlice: 31.575808ms 
printSlice faster?: true

6
printSlice: 1.038342ms 
joinSlice: 27.515216ms 
printSlice faster?: true

7
printSlice: 34.409332ms 
joinSlice: 8.32355ms 
printSlice faster?: false

8
printSlice: 1.20479ms 
joinSlice: 30.070951ms 
printSlice faster?: true

9
printSlice: 1.479724ms 
joinSlice: 34.551614ms 
printSlice faster?: true

10
printSlice: 977.179µs 
joinSlice: 442.46µs 
printSlice faster?: false
```

So in 8 out of 10 tests, printSlice was faster. The difference came down to microseconds in one test, milliseconds in another. If anyone knows a better way to repeat this test, feel free to edit or make a suggestion.